# program returning garbage values

Tags: c, garbage

This program is returning garbage values in output of total marks and average marks.
even after declaring s.total=0 and s.marks[15]=0 in the beginning of program

```
//student database
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    struct student
{
    int name[20];
    int roll[5];
    int total;
    float avg;
    int marks[15];
};
    struct student s;
    int subject_no,i;
    s.total=0;
    s.marks[15]=0;  
    printf("Enter the name of student:\t");
    scanf("%s",s.name);
    printf("enter the roll no:\t");
    scanf("%d",&s.roll);
    printf("Enter the number of subjects:\t");
    scanf("%d",&subject_no);
    for(i=0;i<subject_no;i++)
{
    printf("Enter marks in subject %d:\t",i);
    scanf("%d",&s.marks);
    s.total=s.total+s.marks[i];
}
    printf("total marks are:%d\n",s.total);
    s.avg=(s.total)/(subject_no);
    printf("The average is :%d",s.avg);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You should probably also tag this with "C". There is a pending edit so i cant add it

Comment: Better make your 20 some defined macro e.g. `#define NAME_LEN 20`

Comment: Learn how to **use a debugger**

Comment: `struct student s = {{0},{0},0,0.0f,{0}};`

Comment: Why did you declare "name" as integer?

Answer (score 2):

This is an illegal memory access: `s.marks[15]=0`.

If you have 15 entries in the array, then legal indexes are between 0 and 14.

So you can do `s.marks[0]=0` or `s.marks[6]=0`, but you **should not** do `s.marks[15]=0`.

If you want to set the entire array to zero values, then you can iterate it:

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(s.marks)/sizeof(*s.marks); i++)
    s.marks[i] = 0;
```

Or simply use `memset`:

```
memset(s.marks,0,sizeof(s.marks));
```

Comment: -Everything you wrote was ok.But the problem with the program was something else.Actually i deleted the s.marks[15] line.It wasn't needed and declared the s.marks[i] in the for loop.But the real problem actually was==== i wrote %d in the last printf statement,but actually i declared it float.so i had to write %f.and the program started working.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly clear your `s`  structure with

```
 memset (&s, 0, sizeof(s));
```

Of course your filling of `s.marks[15]` is out of bounds ([undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and/or [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)!!)

Your code never fills or uses `s.roll[1]` so why make `s.roll` an array?

At last, your first `for` loop should be

```
if (subject_no >= 15) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
for(i=0;i<subject_no;i++) {
  printf("Enter marks in subject %d:\t",i);
  scanf("%d",&s.marks[i]);
  s.total=s.total+s.marks[i];
}
```

Comment: `memset (s, 0, sizeof(s))` will not work. should pass `&s` as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to store the name in a char array, rather than an int array (although that will work)

Also, you have been inconsistent in you use of scanf with arrays.